# Angular best way to handle email confirm route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to work out the best way to define a route that users will click on in the confirmation email that they receive.

I have defined a path like this.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/app/setup/confirm/:code',{
        // code is $routeParams.code
    });
});
```

What needs to happen is:

- Make a $http call to the api resource that logs the code as being
  clicked and confirms email address
- Log the user in for both the api and front end
- Return the user to the next step of the setup process now their email is confirmed.
- If the code is bogus and the $http call returns false then redirect them to the signup page.

As this route doesn't need a template, I can't work out where to put the code to do this. If I only defined a controller it never gets instantiated until I also define a template??

For example this works

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/app/setup/confirm/:code',{
            controller: function($routeParams){
                console.log($routeParams.code);
            },
            template: function(){
                return '<html></html>';
            }
    });
});
```

But as soon as I remove the `template` or even return an empty string in the template the controller doesn't work. There must be right way to do this and this doesn't feel like it.

Can anyone give me a pointer? I'm using v1.1.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve the request to a controller without specifying the template. Try this pattern:

```
app.factory('myService', function () {
    return 1;
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    console.log(myService);
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/app/setup/confirm/:code', {
        resolve: {
            redirect: 'MainCtrl'
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Using this pattern of defining the controller I get a `Error: Unknown provider:` error. :(